# Photoshop Ctrl+Click on layer with feathering, (gradient transparency) does not select all pixels

Tags: adobe-photoshop, selections, shortcuts

If i make transparent layer and inside draw circle with feathering then click Ctrl+Click on layer icon  it then cut the pixels i will see that some feathered pixels are left on the layer.

Why Photoshop cannot select all pixels its been issue since as long as i remember prior CS6 and until now.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Can't you just do Ctrl/Cmd+A (select all), then cut?

Comment: Hello, i can of course Ctrl+A, my question about Ctrl+Click if this is bug or a feature, if its a feature what's the purpose of it, if its a bug why not fixed?

Comment: I wouldn't call it a bug. It's just not working in the way that you want it to. It's pretty normal otherwise. The behaviour is similar in other image editors such as GIMP (alpha to selection, then cut) or Krita (select opaque, then cut). If you want to cut all the pixels, I suggest you use Ctrl+A then cut.

Comment: Might be better to show an example of what you are actually trying to achieve if Ctrl+click or Ctrl+A isn't doing what you want. There may be better ways to achieve your goal. At the moment your questions reads a bit like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: I am not trying to achieve anything i am trying to figure out a use case for this feature?

Comment: Ctrl+click on a layer can be used for creating layer masks, i.e. to make a selection, then apply the selection as a mask. It really depends on what you are doing though. There's no single "use case".

Comment: Ctrl+Click loads the layer is selection. If a pixel is 50% opaque, the selection will be 50% opaque. If you cut a 50% opaque selection from 50% opaque pixel you'll get a 25% opaque pixel. So it's working as intended

Comment: @Sergey Kritskiy could not find any documentation regarding this functionality on adobe website, could you point to where they describe that its intended use rather than a bug?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to find? It's not a particular feature of Photoshop, just how math works